# Looking into password protecting a settings screen

Tags: android, password-protection

I am working on an app that will have a parental settings feature to it and I am trying to find a way to password protect it so that the kids dont have direct access to it with out the parents password.

How would I go about doing this?

Granted I would show code but to this point the settings screen is more or less just the layout for it and nothing more.

Chances are I will want to set this in the activity before it so when the button to go to Parental settings is pressed it brings up a new activity or even an alert that requires the user to authenticate then it allows them to progress into the parental settings. Password failure comes up with a warning and kicks you back to the normal settings screen.

Comment: What part are you unsure about?

Comment: @codeMagic Exactly how to do this. I am guessing it would be like how I save a default number if I wanted to make a phone app. Edit text with a save button save button gathers info from edit text and puts it into a global variable to be used to cross reference with that specific password?

Comment: Yeah, I would save it in `SharedPref`s say the first time the app is run and have a place in the parental settings where they can change the pw

Comment: Then the shared prefs file can hold more than one password? - Just making sure before I dive into this. Also if you will drop that and a brief tutorial (If you want) below and I'll make it as answered. -- Thank you :)

Comment: I will write something up that can hopefully give a little better explanation and options

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a few suggestions...

**Get initial pw**

When the app is run the first time you have a pw entered into an `EditText` then saved to `SharedPreferences` with a save `Button`. Now this is stored.

**Compare**

When the user tries to bring up the parental screen, you show a `Dialog` maybe with a custom `View` or a dialog themed `Activity` for the user to enter the pw and compare that to what you have in `SharedPreferences`.

**Options**

You can store this in `SharedPreferences` if you aren't planning on having too much data stored. If you have multiple users, as long as it won't be a large amount, I would say `SharedPrefs` is fine. If the amount of users will be large and you may want to store more data then I would suggest using SQLLite DB.

**Suggested Links**

[Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

[SharedPrefs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) has a good example of getting started

[Complete SharedPrefs Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

[SQLite DB](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)